# Replace certain values of a vector with NA

Tags: r

I am trying to replace the values of the vector with NA if the value == -273.17.

Here's a sample data:

```
x <- c(32,33,34,-273.17,32)
```

I would like to get this:

```
x <- c(32,33,34,NA,32)
```

Here's what I tried

```
x <- apply(x, 1, 
                (if (x==-273.17)
                 {x==NA} ))
```

But I get an error instead. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boolean indexing, similar to answer from @Konrad.Rudolph, using tolerance based on default for `?all.equal`:

```
tol <- 0.5 * .Machine$double.eps # tolerance close to machine precision
float.equal <- function(a, b, p.tol = tol) { abs(a - b) < p.tol }
x[float.equal(x, -273.17)] <- NA
```

Consider the following if your requirement can be reduced to an easier-to-code predicate, e.g.:

```
x[x<0] <- NA
```

`all.equal` works on vectors of equal length, and reports on the equality of full objects being compared, not element-wise equality.

For R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16), `isTRUE(all.equal())` does not produce the desired result:

```
> all.equal(x, -273.17)
[1] "Numeric: lengths (5, 1) differ"
> isTRUE(all.equal(x, -273.17))
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: I didn't test Konald's answer do I didn't know it doesn't work anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You’d normally use subsetting for this:

```
x[x == -273.17] <- NA
```

However, beware of comparing floating point numbers in this fashion. [`all.equal`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/all.equal.html) is a better alternative because it takes into account the inaccuracy in representation:

```
x[isTRUE(all.equal(x, -273.17))] <- NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ifelse`

```
ifelse(x==-273.17, NA, x)
```

but I like @KonradRudolph answer more.

Comment: Your's is easier to understand though.