# Replace a subset of vector with NA using conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Trying to replace values in a column with NA using the condition: if sensor is equal to 2032, and date is less than 2019-01-29 replace all values in column "temperature" with NA.

I have tried the code below but getting an error "argument "true" is missing, with no default"

`filter(if_else(sensor == 2032 & date(date_time) < 2019-01-29), NA, temperature)`

I have seen this solution but could not get it to work for me:

[Replace certain values of a vector with NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511237/replace-certain-values-of-a-vector-with-na)

Comment: `dplyr::filter` subsets rows, but doesn't assign; you'd need `mutate`

Comment: Thanks @alistaire; this worked for me: ```mutate(temperature = ifelse(sensor == == 2032 & date(DateTime) < "2019-01-29", NA, temperature))``` if_else is returning an error though something to do with data types being different. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, `if_else` cares about which `NA` you use, so you may need `NA_integer_` or `NA_real_`. And your code looks like it has two sets of `==` for some reason.

Comment: Thanks alistaire! == is a typo that I can't edit here now